# How can I build a progress bar window or something like that in sharepoint?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, display-form

I want a progress bar to be displayed when I upload multiple documents. The progress bar should display the percent of documents uploaded just like how we attach documents in Gmail. How can I achieve it?

Comment: How you are uploading the documents? Is it through custom code or out of the box upload form? Can you post relevant code. Also tag SharePoint version.

Comment: @AmalHashim I am uploading it through a customized form